# If my bag is full when I visit a PokeStop, do I still get credit for the stop?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I stop at a PokeStop and my bag is full, I get an alert that says my bag is full, but I still get the XP and the stop turns purple, indicating that it has been visited.  Does visiting a stop when your bag is full still count towards the PokeStop visits badge progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It increases the number on the badge counter. I've tested this hitting several stops after filling my bag, and they all counted.